# c# Display sum of columns total in gridview footer using asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I need display sum of Columns total (**Grand Total**) in **GridView Footer** in ASP.Net using C#.

I have two problems:

1. I can't apply the css style in **GridView Footer**;
2. I have error

> Specified cast is not valid.

when add the Sum of Tot2.

How to resolve this?

Thank you advance for any help.

This is SQL query:

```
        sql = " SELECT ZN, ";
        sql += "    IFNULL(Tot1,0) AS Tot1, ";
        sql += "    IFNULL(Tot2,0) AS Tot2 ";
        sql += " FROM ";
        sql += "    doTable ";
        sql += " ORDER BY ";
        sql += "    Tot1 DESC; ";

+----+------+------+
| Zn | Tot1 | Tot2 |
+----+------+------+
| ZO |    3 |    0 |
| ZO |    3 |    0 |
| ZO |    2 |    1 |
| ZO |    2 |    0 |
| ZO |    2 |    0 |
| ZO |    2 |    0 |
| ZO |    2 |    0 |
| ZO |    1 |    0 |
| ZO |    1 |    1 |
| ZO |    1 |    0 |
+----+------+------+
10 rows in set
```

This the **code-behind**:

```
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(dsProducts);

gvProducts.Columns[1].FooterText = "Total";
gvProducts.Columns[2].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
gvProducts.Columns[2].ItemStyle.CssClass = "ddl_Class_new";
gvProducts.Columns[2].FooterText = dsProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("Tot1")).Sum().ToString();

gvProducts.Columns[3].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
gvProducts.Columns[3].ItemStyle.CssClass = "ddl_Class_new";
gvProducts.Columns[3].FooterText = dsProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("Tot2")).Sum().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you set the css of the footer with `FooterStyle.CssClass`

```
gvProducts.Columns[3].FooterStyle.CssClass = "ddl_Class_new";
```

And specified cast means that there are fields in `Tot1` or `Tot2` that are not convertible to `Int32`. Probably because you use `IFNULL` in your query, change that to `ISNULL` if you use MS SQL or check if the data in aspnet is what you actually expect it to be by debugging.